API Яндекс получать отзывы на свои созданные организации
Возможно ли с помощью API Яндекс.Карт или Яндекс.Бизнес получить отзывы на свои ранее созданные организации?
Нашел такую ссылку
https://yandex.ru/maps/api/business/fetchReviews?ajax=1&businessId=id_организации&csrfToken={$token}&page=1&pageSize=5
Но что указывать в "Доступ к данным" самого приложения тут: https://oauth.yandex.ru/client/new непонятно

Отзывы являются частью сервиса Бизнес. Работать с ними можно только в интерфейсе сервиса. Публичных API для работы с ними напрямую не существует. Любое использование недокументированных методов для копирования, воспроизведения, переработки, либо иного использования вне рамок возможностей, предоставляемых Сервисом запрещено.
